# How can I prevent users from downloading documents created in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I know I have the ability to prevent viewers from downloading documents which are not native to Google Drive (http://chromebytes.com/1717/prevent-viewers-from-downloading-google-docs-files) however how can I achieve the same effect with Google Drive native documents?

Comment: How exactly are you publishing the native document to the public?

Comment: The most straightforward way would be to deny them viewing rights.

Answer (score 1):

Download the documents to your desktop and upload them again thus making them non native documents. You will still be able to make changes to these documents.